# UIButton is highlighted but doesn't perform its action

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, textfield, swift4.2

I have a tableView with different rows. The majority of them are filled with cells that contains TextFields, the last one is a cell that contains a UIStackView in which are displayed two UIButtons. Basically, my goal is to have a tableView that works like a form, each rows would take some info and finally when the user clicks one of the two buttons at the bottom all the info are saved (the other button should cancel the operation and get back to the previous view).
Now, all the textfields are working good, and in "idle" state, the buttons are working good too and do what they need to do.

The problem is the following: while in editing mode of one of textField, if I click one of the buttons at the bottom they HIGHLIGHT (so something is happening) but they DO NOT perform their action. What happens next is that the keyboard is dismissed (the textField resigns from being first responder) and all get back to "idle state". At this point, the buttons get back to working good (so if clicked again they perform their action etc).

I would like them to work even if the focus is on the editing mode of the other cells, and I don't want the user to be forced of clicking two times the same button. 
What can I do?

I've tried all possible properties of both the tableView, the UIButtons and even the StackView (so "isInteractionEnabled", "AllowsMultipleSelectionWhileEditing", "delaysContentTouches" etc, "BringSubviewToFront"..)
I have no idea why the button is highlighting but not working.

There is also a tapGestureRecognizer in the mix, but it doesn't seem to get involved (I print something every time is called, and this is not the case).

**Here's my code.**

**In the ButtonCell init:**

```
modButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(modClicked()), for: .touchUpInside)
saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveClicked()), for: .touchUpInside)
//some other properties of the buttons

buttonStack.alignment = .center
buttonStack.axis = .horizontal
buttonStack.distribution = .equalSpacing
buttonStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(modButton)
buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(saveButton)

addSubview(buttonStack)
//some constraints
```

**In the viewDidLoad method:**

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenTouched))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

//some properties i've tried

tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.separatorColor = .clear
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
tableView.allowsSelection = true
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

**In the tableView cellForRow method:**

```
// at the right indexPath:

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttoncell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

//some properties i've tried

cell.buttonStack.bringSubviewToTop
cell.buttonStack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.buttonStack.allowsMultipleInteraction = true

cell.modButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

//etc..

return cell
```

Comment: Have you tried to add target like this? ```saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveClicked()), for: .touchUpInside)```

Comment: Hi Ekrem, yes sure, I posted that line like that only for laziness. The method is working, I think the issue is that there is something that is "stealing" the first tap..
thnx anyway, I fixed that